# Error loading PyQt5 UI file

Tags: python, user-interface, load

I am using following code to load a ui file, but keep seeing an error message.

---

```
# main.py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("main_window.ui")[0]

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

```
Error message:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main_window.ui'
```

`main_window.ui` is located in the same folder as `main.py`

Comment: what directory are you executing the file from?

Comment: I am using desktop folder. That is, both are on(in) a desktop folder. Anyway, when I used "C:\Anaconda3" folder, I had a same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the file you pass to `loadUiType` is relative to the working directory, not your python file. You can pass the full path instead. To get the full path, you can find the directory of your current file and then join that with the name of your UI file.

e.g:

```
...
ui_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
form_class = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(ui_path, "main_window.ui"))[0]
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I will include the full path.